# RegEx: URI parts from text

Tags: c#, .net, regex, uri

all! I have a text like this "Some text with uri http://test.com and other words.". And I need to get parts of uri using **one** regular expression.

I try this:

```
string text = "Some text with uri http://test.com and other words.";
string pattern = @"\b(\S+)://([^:]+)(?::(\S+))?\b"; 
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
```

And it works, when i write "Some text with uri http://test.com" or "word1 http://test.com:5000 word2".

Where is mistake?

Comment: What's not working?  You say "it works".

Comment: My guess is that this is returning `http://test.com and other words.` Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second `+` modifier is greedy, so it's matching everything after the `http://` unless it hits a `:` or the end of the line. Try this:

```
@"\b(\w+)://([^:]+?)(?::(\S+))?\b"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you closer... I"m still not exactly sure what you want to get...

If you could show the results you want it would help...

```
\b(\S+)://([^: ]+)
```